# Asyncio и aiohttp отправка запросов

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, aiohttp

Я не совсем понимаю, как работает aiohttp вместе с create_task с asyncio, порой всё работает так как нужно, а порой наоборот.

Я написал небольшой код, который казалось бы, что должен вывести результаты после отправки запросов, но это не происходит, ошибок никаких нет, код просто прекращает работу:

```
    from asyncio import create_task, run
from aiohttp import ClientSession

PARSING_LINKS = [
    '' # я убрал отсюда ссылки, перед тем как вставить код сюда, но они тут были
]


async def GET_PRODUCTS_INFO(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as request_response:
            print(request_response.status)


async def main():
    for TTT__ in PARSING_LINKS:
        create_task(GET_PRODUCTS_INFO(url=TTT__))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

Я пытаюсь запустить одну и туже функцию с другой ссылкой в переменной TTT___, которая получает значение с списка со ссылками, спустя секунду мой код просто закрывается вывода никакого нет. Я не знаю, как можно правильно параллельно запустить другие функции в этом коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подождать, когда корутина запущенная с помощью `create_task` закончится:

```
async def main():
    tasks = []
    for TTT__ in PARSING_LINKS:
        tasks.append(create_task(GET_PRODUCTS_INFO(url=TTT__)))
    for task in tasks:
        await task
```

Comment: Раскрыли инфу про потоки и асинхронность, благодарю.